# $\int_0^1 \frac{x^p}{1-x^q}\; dx＝∞$

Tags: inequality, improper-integrals

When $p>-1, \;q>0$, I want to prove
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^p}{1-x^q}\; dx = \infty.$$

Any help would be appreciated.  I observed by graph soft this is true, but I cannot prove.  I want to find some function $\varphi(x)$ which satisfies

$$\int_0^1 \varphi(x)dx = \infty,$$
such that
$ \frac{x^p}{1-x^q}>\varphi(x)$.
Thank you.

Comment: Note that $\varphi$ diverging at $0$ doesn't prove $\int_0^1\varphi dx$ diverges, because e.g. $\int_0^1x^{-1/2}dx=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: It is enough to show that $\int_{1/2}^{1} \frac  1 {1-x^{q}}dx=\infty$ (because $\inf \{x^{p}: \frac 1 2 \leq x \leq 1\} >0$). Expand $\frac  1 {1-x^{q}}$ as $\sum_n x^{nq}$ and integrate term by term. Compare with $\sum \frac 1  n$.

Answer (score 0):

It diverges about $x = 1$.  To see this, substitute $y = 1-x$.  This transforms the integral to
$ \int_0^1 f(y) \, dy$ where
$$ f(y) = \frac{(1-y)^p}{1-(1-y)^q} $$
Note that
$$  (1-y)^q = 1 - q y + O(y^2) $$
and hence
$$ f(y) \sim \frac{1}{q y} $$
as $y \to 0$.  But $\int_0^1 dy/y = \infty$.

The $x^p = (1-y)^p$ in the numerator is a red-herring.